# How can you sum index items that are being pushed into an array that is initially empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to find the sum of all numbers in an array. The numbers are being pushed into the array when the user clicks an image on the page. Do I need to use a for loop or something different since the array is continuously being updated?

I've tried using .reduce() and an arrow function with no success. The console is returning an error that there is no initial value in the array, so I put the number 0 in there, but the function won't include any of the numbers being pushed in.

```
//user clicks HTML element
$("#yellowcrystal").on('click', function () {

 //value of number must differ from the other clicked HTML elements
     if (yellowCrystalNum !== redCrystalNum && yellowCrystalNum !== 
     blueCrystalNum && yellowCrystalNum !== greenCrystalNum){
          crystals.push(yellowCrystalNum); 
     } else {
          yellowCrystalNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
     } 
});

//empty array to hold values 
var crystals = []
```

Comment: You can pass the initial value of 0 into the `reduce` method. `[].reduce( ( total, num ) => total + num, 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```js
//user clicks HTML element
var crystals = []
var sum = 0;

$("#yellowcrystal").on('click', function () {

 //value of number must differ from the other clicked HTML elements
     if (yellowCrystalNum !== redCrystalNum && yellowCrystalNum !== 
     blueCrystalNum && yellowCrystalNum !== greenCrystalNum){
        crystals.push(yellowCrystalNum); 
        // use it here maybe
        sum = arrsum(crystals)
     } else {
          yellowCrystalNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
     } 
});

function arrsum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(xs, x) {
        return xs + x
    }, 0)
}
```

Comment: Clever. I tried it, I feel like it's close but I'm still not returning any sum. I'm returning undefined for whatever reason. Here's the app: https://rob-canfield.github.io/unit-4-game/. not sure if that provides a more clear perspective.